# How does Babel deal with ES6 import?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules, transpiler

I just started looking into Babel. From my understanding, Babel attempts to convert ES6 code into older JS versions for better browser support. This is pretty simple for stuff like template literals. And it is even possible with classes. But how does it handle `import`?

I am also confused why sometimes it converts `import` into `require`, because `require` is node.js specific, and it definitely would not work on any browser.

Comment: Babel transpiles your code. A bundler bundles your code, creating one file with all the source code and dependencies. AFAIK can't bundle. Usually you would use Webpack, Browserify, Parcel or Rollup for this.

Comment: @jabaa So Webpack is also used for backward compatibility (and performance)? Like if I didn't care much about performance or browser support, could I just use ES6 import and no bundler

Comment: Webpack is a bundler. You can use it to bundle multiple files containing `import` or `require` statements to one (or a few) target file(s). Babel is a transpiler. It converts one language (standard) to another language (standard). Babel can convert TypeScript to JavaScript or JavaScript ES6 to JavaScript ES3. With modern browsers, you can use ES6 imports without bundler.